# Python: Replace tags but preserve inner text V2

Tags: python, regex, replace

I've got a script to do search and replace. it's based on a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236243/python-replace-tags-but-preserve-inner-text).
It was modified to accept file as input but it does not seem to recognize regex well.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
import re
import glob

_replacements = {
    '[B]': '**',
    '[/B]': '**',
    '[I]': '//',
    '[/I]': '//',

}

def _do_replace(match):
    return _replacements.get(match.group(0))

def replace_tags(text, _re=re.compile('|'.join((r) for r in _replacements))): 
    return _re.sub(_do_replace, text)

def getfilecont(FN):
    if not glob.glob(FN): return -1 # No such file
    text = open(FN, 'rt').read()
    text = replace_tags(text, re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(r) for r in _replacements)))
    return replace_tags(text)

scriptName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
if sys.argv[1:]:
    srcfile = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])[0]
else:
    print """%s: Error you must specify file, to convert forum tages to wiki tags!
            Type %s FILENAME """ % (scriptName, scriptName)
    exit(1)
dstfile = os.path.join('.' , os.path.basename(srcfile)+'_wiki.txt')
converted = getfilecont(srcfile)
try:
    open(dstfile, 'wt+').write(converted)
    print 'Done.'
except:
    print 'Error saving file %s' % dstfile

print converted
#print replace_tags("This is an [[example]] sentence. It is [[{{awesome}}]].")
```

What I want is to replace

```
'[B]': '**',
'[/B]': '**',
```

with only one line like this as in regex

```
\[B\](.*?)\[\/B\] : **\1**
```

That very would be helpful with BBcode tags like this:

```
[FONT=Arial]Hello, how are you?[/FONT]
```

Then I can use something like this

```
\[FONT=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/FONT\] : ''\2''
```

But I can not seem to be able to do that with this script. There are another ways to do regex search and replace in the original source of this script but it works for one tag at a time using re.sub. Other advantage of this script that I can add as many line as I want so I can update it later.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you're escaping the patterns on this line:

```
text = replace_tags(text, re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(r) for r in _replacements)))
```

`re.escape` takes a string and escapes it in such a way that if the new string were used as a regex it would match exactly the input string.

Removing the re.escape won't entirely solve your problem, however, ans you find the replacement by just doing a lookup of the matched text in your dict on this line:

```
return _replacements.get(match.group(0))
```

To fix this you could make each pattern into its own capture group:

```
text = replace_tags(text, re.compile('|'.join('(%s)' % r for r in _replacements)))
```

You'll also need to know which pattern goes with which substitution. Something like this might work:

```
_replacements_dict = {
    '[B]': '**',
    '[/B]': '**',
    '[I]': '//',
    '[/I]': '//',
}
_replacements, _subs = zip(*_replacements_dict.items())

def _do_replace(match):
    for i, group in m.groups():
        if group:
            return _subs[i]
```

Note that this changes `_replacements` into a list of the patterns, and creates a parallel array `_subs` for the actual replacements. (I would have named them regexes and replacements, but didn't want to have to re-edit every occurrence of "_replacements").

Answer (score 0):

Someone has done it [here](http://www.linuxac.org/forum/showthread.php?46515&p=373168&viewfull=1#post373168).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
import re
import glob

_replacements_dict = {
    '\[B\]': '**',
    '\[\/B\]': '**',
    '\[I\]': '//',
    '\[\/I\]': '//',
    '\[IMG\]' : '{{',
    '\[\/IMG\]' : '}}',
    '\[URL=(.*?)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/URL\]' : r'[[\1|\2]]',
    '\[URL\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/URL\]' : r'[[\1]]',
    '\[FONT=(.*?)\]' : '',
    '\[color=(.*?)\]' : '',
    '\[SIZE=(.*?)\]' : '',
    '\[CENTER]' : '',
    '\[\/CENTER]' : '',
    '\[\/FONT\]' : '',
    '\[\/color\]' : '',
    '\[\/size\]' : '',
}
_replacements, _subs = zip(*_replacements_dict.items())

def replace_tags(text):
    for i, _s in enumerate(_replacements):
        tag_re = re.compile(r''+_s,  re.I) 
        text, n = tag_re.subn(r''+_subs[i], text)
    return text


def getfilecont(FN):
    if not glob.glob(FN): return -1 # No such file
    text = open(FN, 'rt').read()
    return replace_tags(text)

scriptName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
if sys.argv[1:]:
    srcfile = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])[0]
else:
    print """%s: Error you must specify file, to convert forum tages to wiki tags!
            Type %s FILENAME """ % (scriptName, scriptName)
    exit(1)
dstfile = os.path.join('.' , os.path.basename(srcfile)+'_wiki.txt')
converted = getfilecont(srcfile)
try:
    open(dstfile, 'wt+').write(converted)
    print 'Done.'
except:
    print 'Error saving file %s' % dstfile

#print converted
#print replace_tags("This is an [[example]] sentence. It is [[{{awesome}}]].")
```

http://pastie.org/1447448